# Getting rid of irritating dead battery notification

Tags: 18.04, gnome, power-management, battery, notification

My laptop battery is dead forever. It needs to be replaced. Since it is not working anymore, GNOME detects it as low battery and keeps popping up as notification on notification area. A screenshot for reference:

[image]

Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Note: I have got Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my laptop with GNOME desktop environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try taking out the battery? This may prevent it from being detected, and stop the notification appearing.

Comment: I was less lucky. After my battery was removed, the laptop would not boot. So this is not always an option.

Comment: Hey! @fregger it worked. Thanks Could you reword it to make it look like an answer?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Glad I could help. I usually take out my laptop's battery anyway when operating it for extended periods while connected to AC power. It can help preserve its life. See also https://www.lifewire.com/remove-your-laptops-battery-when-plugged-in-2378119